# Get folder from windows service(system.io) to Windows store App (Windows.Storage)

Tags: .net, vb.net, windows-store-apps, windows-8.1, storage

I currently have an application which needs to retrieve images from a server and copy them locally on a tablet. The problem is that I don't have access to the server from my application. This is why I use a Windows Service to get data from my database or in this case a folder.

I am struggling to find a common ground between the 2 imports (`system.io` and `Windows.Storage`)

How can I get a directory using System.IO then send it back to my client which will use Windows.Storage to copy it locally ?

I will also consider any alternatives

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking for a while this seems quite impossible to do. However I have found a way to go around the problem by passing each file 1 by 1 into a `memorystream`.

It is possible to store an image into a `memorystream` and then, on the client, take that `stream` and affect it to an existing file.

Go take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29967831/transfer-images-from-server-to-local-folder-windows-store-app#comment48055683_29967831) where I explained everything step by step.