# Transfer images from server to local folder Windows Store App

Tags: .net, vb.net, web-services, windows-store-apps, file-transfer

Here is my situation :

- I have a *windows service* with access to the files on the server
- A *Windows Store Apps* with access to said service
- *Windows Store Apps* don't have access to the `bitmap` object (only `bitmapimage`)
- The service has access to `bitmap` but not `bitmapimage`
- The service only has access to `file.io`
- *Windows Store Apps* only have access to `Windows.Storage`

I am having difficulties finding a way to pass all my images from the service to the *Windows Store App* as I can't find a **common ground between the 2**.

I have tried to transfer a `bitmap` and convert it to a `bitmapimage` but then I could not find a way to save the BitmapImage to a specific folder.

Any idea of what could put me on the right track as far as finding a common object to transfer ?

Comment: Intuition suggests looking to see if you can convert the image data into bytes or a byte array and transfer them that way, either as a file or stream.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Big Thanks to ChicagoMike for putting me on the right track. Here is how I did it

Object to transfer from the service to the client :

```
Imports System.IO

    Public Class PictureSender
        Public Property PictureBytes As Byte()
        Public Property PictureName As String
    End Class
```

Code on the client calling its controller (The linq and For loop is useful in my case since I have multiple types of images in their respective folders):

```
    Private Async Sub btnGetPictures_Click(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs)
        ' Get the list of all categories of picture to go through all folders from local saves.
        Dim lstFolders As List(Of String) = (From p In Await ImageController.GetImageDetails Select p.Categorie).Distinct.ToList()
        For i = 0 To lstFolders.Count - 1
            PicturesController.GetPicturesServer(lstFolders(i))
        Next
    End Sub
```

Code in the client controller :

```
    Public Async Sub GetPicturesServer(_folderName As String)
        Dim service As New ServiceReference1.Service1Client(ServiceReference1.Service1Client.EndpointConfiguration.BasicHttpBinding_IService1)

        Dim rcv = Await service.SelectAllPicturesAsync(_folderName)

        ' Get the folder
        Dim folder = ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder
        folder = Await folder.CreateFolderAsync("Images", CreationCollisionOption.OpenIfExists)
        Await folder.CreateFolderAsync(_folderName, CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting)
        folder = Await folder.GetFolderAsync(_folderName)

        ' Run through all pictures and save them
        For i = 0 To rcv.Count - 1
            Dim myfile As StorageFile = CType(Await folder.CreateFileAsync(rcv(i).PictureName, CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting), StorageFile)
            Await Windows.Storage.FileIO.WriteBufferAsync(myfile, rcv(i).PictureBytes.AsBuffer())
        Next
```

Code on the service :

```
    Function Execute(TypeOfPictures As String) As List(Of PictureSender)
        Dim PicturesinDirectory As List(Of String) = Directory.GetFiles("\\SERVER\Data\Image\" + TypeOfPictures + "\", "*.jpg*").ToList()

        Dim lstPicturesToSend As List(Of PictureSender) = New List(Of PictureSender)
        For i = 0 To PicturesinDirectory.Count - 1
            Dim ByteArray As Byte() = File.ReadAllBytes(PicturesinDirectory(i))

            ' Affect the PictureSender object
            Dim PictureSenderObject As PictureSender = New PictureSender
            PictureSenderObject.PictureBytes = ByteArray
            PictureSenderObject.PictureName = PicturesinDirectory(i).Substring(PicturesinDirectory(i).LastIndexOf("\") + 1)
            lstPicturesToSend.Add(PictureSenderObject)
        Next
        Return lstPicturesToSend

    End Function
```

This code pretty much sends back a `Byte()` and a picture name from the service which is then used by the client. The client uses the `buffer` to write on the files and recreating the picture